# Is There a Word of Phrase that denotes the ending of a never ending conflict?

Tags: single-word-requests, book-title

The idea is that there is a contest, or a battle, between two opponents that are so equally matched, so eternally against each other, that they end up both destroyed. But this doesn't happen until all forces, all resources have been marshaled for one or the other side up-to optimum efficiency. You can also think of it as perfect play by both sides: e.g. Neither side ever makes a mistake nor yields to the other, until only the ultimate, logical conclusion of mutual destruction is reached?

This is for the subtitle of a book, by the way. One in a series of several. The above conflict is the central theme of this one. All the subtitles of all the books follow the pattern of: "Arc of `<word>`". So, for example, "Arc of Enmity", or "Arc of Eredtgauss", etc. I'm looking for a `<word>` that can fit the pattern and express the central theme as described above.

Thank you for reading, and for any and all help!

Comment: ... Of Mutual Destruction.    ....Annihilation

Comment: Thank you! Also, it seems I was downvoted 2 times immediately. I probably did something wrong, as I only joined for this question. My apologies.

Comment: Should this question be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

In games, such situations can be called, depending on how you view the situation, a [draw](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw), [stalemate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stalemate), [deadlock](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deadlock), or [standstill](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standstill) (all Merriam-Webster definitions).

---

In situations that are seemingly unending, yet do still end, it means that some variable is introduced that had not been factored into initial considerations or predictions:

- The contest is over, but there is no winner—unless that is defined as the other person losing. (This would cover something like mutual destruction and Pyrrhic victories.)
- The rules (or variables) of the game are changed mid-game, thereby allowing a winner where there would have been none before.
- The rules of the game are changed mid-game, or the game is abandoned altogether, in such a way that the terms *winner* and *loser* become irrelevant.

A word that describes the final end-state of such a conflict (assuming that one of the stalemate synonyms is not more appropriate) is simply [**conclusion**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conclusion):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : the last part of something • The team was exhausted at the *conclusion* of the game. : such as
> **a** : RESULT, OUTCOME • The peace talks came to a successful *conclusion*.
> **b conclusions** *plural* : trial of strength or skill —used in the phrase *try conclusions*
> **c** : a final summation • the counsel's *conclusion* to the jury
> **d** : the final decision in a law case
> **e** : the final part of a pleading in law

Finally, something that makes a statement *about* a particular conclusion, would be a [verdict](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verdict), [judgment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judgment), or even [solution](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solution) (all Merriam-Webster definitions).